# CSS - Rails 4 - Boostrap -

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using rails 4 and I have an issue with css :
There's a below-navbar div in my `application.html.erb` which is supposed to be sized to the window size; it works fine with all the layouts except for one.

Here is my `application.html.erb` :

```
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title).presence || "Krawd" %></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<%= (yield(:description).presence || "").squish %>">

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favico.png' %>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, media: "all" %>

  <%= yield(:stylesheets) %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
  <%= render "shared/flashes" %>
 <!--  <div class="animation-loader padded">
    <span class='loading style-1'></span>
  </div> -->
  <div class="below-navbar">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>


  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= yield(:after_js) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the layout which does not work :

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-grey">   

  <h1>New project</h1>
    <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Is that layout the only layout that's wrapped in a div with class `container-fluid`? If so, that could be the reason.

Comment: No there's many others wrapped with it. I already tryed to change it. It didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the div container-fluid in the application controller layout around the yield statement and take it out of the project model it will then apply to all models. Just leave the colour CSS there.

```html
<body>
<dix class = "container-fluid"> # HERE
  <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
  <%= render "shared/flashes" %>
 <!--  <div class="animation-loader padded">
    <span class='loading style-1'></span>
  </div> -->
  <div class="below-navbar">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>


  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= yield(:after_js) %>
</div> # HERE
</body>
```